# SPOCK - All @Shared Variables are NULL

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

Here is my test class:

```
import grails.test.mixin.*
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll
import spock.lang.*
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j

@Slf4j
@Mock([PromoRule, PromoCode, SecUser])
@TestFor(PromoService)
class PromoServiceSpec extends Specification {

@Shared testUser
@Shared testCode
@Shared testRule

def setup() {

}

@Unroll
def 'valid promo codes - #user, #code'() {
    given:
    testRule = new PromoRule(
            name : "ZTEST",
            receiverAmount : 5,
            receiverAmountType : PromoRule.AmountType.DOLLARS,
            senderAmount : 0,
            senderAmountType : PromoRule.AmountType.DOLLARS,
            receiverPointsAmount : null,
            receiverPointsAmountType : null,
            receiverMaxUse : null,
    )
    testRule.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)

    testUser = new SecUser(
            id: 1,
            version: 0,
            accountExpired: false,
            accountLocked: false,
            age: 9000,
            balance: 100,
            dateCreated: new Date(),
            emailVerified: true,
            enabled: true,
            firstName: 'Sir',
            lastName: 'Buttocks',
            lastUpdated: new Date(),
            lockedBalance: 0,
            username: "1",
            staff: false,
            displayName: 'sir_buttocks',
            usernameChosen: true,
            depositMade: true,
            depositOfferRecentlySeen: false,
            pin: null
    )
    testUser.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

    testCode = new PromoCode(
            rule : testRule,
            code : "3",
            senderId : 1,
    )
    testCode.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)

    expect:
    service.isValidPromoCode(user, code) == value

    where:
    user | code || value
    testUser | testCode || true
}
```

}

When I run this test, I get the following:

```
| Failure:  valid promo codes - null, null(skillz.PromoServiceSpec)
|  Condition not satisfied:

service.isValidPromoCode(user, code) == value
|       |                |     |     |  |
|       false            null  null  |  true
skillz.PromoService@20e0e9d5         false
```

I have tried a ton of different configurations and layouts, all of them either getting me a null pointer exception (to the variable itself) or a null value for the variable.

Doing all the definitions at `static` variables didn't change anything either, same result as using `@Shared`.

I've tried mocking these as well, but I always get null exceptions when trying to execute .Mock() for the class...

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you also tried `@Shared def testUser`? Using `def`.

Comment: Yes, no love doing that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve here, but the `where` block is evaluated *before* (the rest of) the method is first entered, and at that time, your shared variables are null. You'd have to set them earlier, e.g. in a `setupSpec` (not `setup`) method.